# Reading dump files - Windows

Tags: windows, dump

I am looking for a documentation to read the content of a crash dump file which happens to be saved under “c:\windows\minidump” folder.
To read the dump files, I am using “dumpchk.exe” tool from Microsoft (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/dumpchk)
. I have used the command

> "dumpchk C:\Windows\Minidump\DumpFile.dmp | clip"

to extract the data from dump file.
The output comes like (it is just the sample data and not the full content from the file):

--Sample START
*Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.3.9600.17788 AMD64'
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\Minidump\101517-22453-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available
*Symbol search path is:*  Invalid *

---

- Symbol loading may be unreliable without a symbol search path.           *
- Use .symfix to have the debugger choose a symbol path.                   *
- After setting your symbol path, use .reload to refresh symbol locations. *
  ****************************************************************************>……..
  *Bugcheck code 0000009F*
  Arguments 00000000`00000004 00000000`0000012c ffffe000`3203e880 ffffd000`d21a9980
  …….**

--Sample END

Now, with all that output I really have no clue how to interpret the content of this file in plain English so that I can use that in my application.

During my hunt, I have found a very wonderful tool from NirSoft (as usual, this guy is awesome. He has solved so many puzzles which you will find nowhere…)
https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html#DownloadLinks
I have really no idea how he had accomplished the following results in his app:

[image]

[Please note that the above tool's result is being used just as a reference to show what I am looking for.]
Basically, I need to find out the **culprit driver (Caused by Driver)** which caused the crash. Therefore, looking for some documentation so that I can understand the content of dump and parse them.

Any details are appreciated. Thanks.